# Sending message with topic to Azure Service bus Queue via HTTP POST?

Tags: rest, azure, http-post, azureservicebus

I was wondering if there is a good way to send a message with a topic to a service bus queue via HTTP Post in postman for example.

I red something about Sas-key encryption but, lets say I would like to expose the url to someone for them to send my service bus messages, how do I do that the simplest way for them so to speak?

I just want them to have a url not crating a program to generate w token for it..

I know the Service Bus has a URL linked to it but I cant seem to send anything to it...

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I just want them to have a url not crating a program to generate w token for it..

From the Azure Service Bus [send message API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message), we could know that Authorization header is required. If want to let someone to use just with a url. In my opinion is that we need to implement it ourself. 
We could develop a **Rest API** service then we could give a rest api url to somebody who want to use. We could get some demo code about how to create topic and send message from the azure [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions).

Comment: I understand, i was actually expecting that answer in some form. Thank you, i will investigate this further. i know there is a possibility to make a logic-app with a request trigger and then do a IP-restriction on the logic-app itself. But i guess that makes it a question of cost, even though the cost per action isn't that high. Anyway Thanks for your answer. @tomsun